# how to invoke a method from an Entry Widget in Ruby Tk

Tags: ruby, events, widget, command, tk-toolkit

I'm looking for an option or a way to bind an event, which invokes a method from an Entry-Widget.

Like the `command` option for button-widgets: `command { method }` or

like binding an event for combobox-widgets: 
`$combobox.bind("<ComboboxSelected>") { method }`

Now I'm looking for something similar for Entry-Widgets. I want to invoke a method every time an entry (value) has been edited. That's my initial situation:

```
$foo = TkVariable.new
$entry = Tk::Tile::Entry.new(parent) {
  validate 'key'; validatecommand method; textvariable $foo
  }
```

`validatecommand` works only at the first time.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the content of the widget during the validation callback and still want to have a validation callback applied in the future, you *must* re-apply the validation callback. This is documented (for the core Tk version of this, see [the end of the validation section](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/entry.htm#M16) of the `entry` docs) but pretty obscure, to be fair.

Use [Tk::after.idle](http://rubydoc.info/github/manveru/ffi-tk/Tk/After) to schedule some code to reapply the validation callback *inside the validation callback*.